# Essential self-adjointness and uses for this operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I was trying to come up with examples of self-adjoint partial differential operators and thought of this: Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be open and let $A:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^d$ be a real $C^1(\Omega)$ vector field. Define the operator $(iA\cdot\nabla,H_0^1(\Omega))$,
$$iA\cdot\nabla f(x):=\sum_{j=1}^d ia_j(x)\partial_{x_j}f(x),$$
where $a_j$ are the component functions of $A$. This is densley defined in $L^2(\Omega)$ and if $\text{div}(A)=0$, then this is also symmetric, as if $g\in H^1(\Omega)$, then
\begin{equation}\begin{split}(ia_j\partial_{x_j}f|g) & =i\int_\Omega a_j\partial_{x_j}f\overline{g}\ dx \\
& =i\int_\Omega \partial_{x_j}f\overline{a_jg}\ dx \\
& =-i\int_\Omega f\overline{(a_j\partial_{x_j}g+g\partial_{x_j}a_j)}\ dx \\
& =\int_\Omega f\overline{i(a_j\partial_{x_j}g+g\partial_{x_j}a_j)}\ dx \end{split}\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{equation}\begin{split}(i A\cdot\nabla f|g) & =\sum_{j=1}^d(ia_j\partial_{x_j}f|g) \\
& =\sum_{j=1}^d\int_\Omega f\overline{i(a_j\partial_{x_j}g+g\partial_{x_j}a_j)}\ dx \\
& =\int_\Omega f\overline{\left(\sum_{j=1}^d ia_j\partial_{x_j}g+ig\sum_{j=1}^d\partial_{x_j}a_j\right)}\ dx \\
& = \int_\Omega f\overline{\left(\sum_{j=1}^d ia_j\partial_{x_j}g+ig\ \text{div}(A)\right)}\ dx \\
& =\int_\Omega f\overline{\sum_{j=1}^d ia_j\partial_{x_j}g}\ dx \\
& =\sum_{j=1}^d(f|i a_j\partial_{x_j} g) \\
& =(f|iA\cdot\nabla g). \end{split}\end{equation}
My question then is in two parts: 1. Could this be essentially self-adjoint or somehow forced to be esentially sef-adjoint?  2. Do you know any places where this kind of operators might be used/of use?

Comment: The operator is not defined on the whole space, which would be $L^2(\Omega)$ here. I don't think this operator is self-adjoint in general, as the same integration by parts argument seems to work for arbitrary $g\in H^1(\Omega)$ so that $H^1(\Omega)$ is contained in the domain of the adjoint.

Comment: Oh yes, i used the wrong inner product. Thank you, i will edit the question to be more relevant.

Comment: Note that the derivative is not essentially self adjoint on the segment $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh ok, so there is not much hope for the operator to be nice in pretty much any way? Except for it being densely defined, symmetric and closable.